# How to Turn off hdd in Ubuntu(not slow down) follow up

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

So, I had the same question seen here: [How to Turn off hdd in Ubuntu(not slow down)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147652/how-to-turn-off-hdd-in-ubuntunot-slow-down)
The only thing that I would like to know is if turning off the HDD would have some risks or downsides? As in the previous question, I am running ubuntu in an SSD M.2 and would like to turn off the HDD that has windows.

Comment: The hardest for HDD is the start. There, the mechanics is fine, the probability of failure will increase significantly. Do you need it?

Comment: I do not need it. It just starts running even though I am booting in the SSD. Is there a way to stop it from turning on when booting in the SSD?

Comment: the only way - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43413/how-can-i-safely-remove-a-sata-disk-from-a-running-system

Comment: Thank you very much.